# Django - 403 (Forbidden): CSRF token missing or incorrect with Ajax call. Tried everything

Tags: django, ajax, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-token

I know this is a well worn question and I scoured the web and this website finding countless answers that boil down to the very same solutions and none of them worked for me and I do not know why. my info/trials so far:

1. suprisingly the `csrf_exempt` decorator does not work
2. tried setting up Headers/beforeSend once before all `Ajax` calls, it does not work (I tried setting the headers both in call and just once for all the `ajax` calls)
3. I can pick up the `django` token easily both via `javascript` or via django `{{ token }}`
4. `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` is present in the `settings.py`
5. `python 3.8; django 2.2`
6. [UPDATE] I tried removing `contentType` to no avail as well

here below you can see the different trials in `/*...*/`

> ```
> var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}'
>
> $.ajaxSetup({
>   crossDomain: false,
>   beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
>       xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
>   }
> });
>
> $.ajax({
>   url: '/do_things/',
>   type: 'POST',
>   contentType: 'application/json',
>   data: {
>     /*'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken*/
>   },
>   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
>       /*xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');*/
>       /*xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);*/
>       /*xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrftoken);*/
>   },
>   headers: {
>       /*'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,*/
>       /*'X-CSRF-Token': csrftoken*/
>   },
>   success: function (data) {
>     console.log('Fill all the tables')
>   }
> })
> ```

on the view side

> ```
> @login_required(login_url='/login/')
> def do_things(request):
>     if request.method == "POST":
>         ...
> ```

on the `url` side ( in case I messed up something here):

> ```
> urlpatterns = [
>     #...
>     path('r/', views.do_things, name='do_things'),
> ]
> ```

Resources:

a) [Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) | Django and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525409/forbidden-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-django-and-ajax)

b) [Adding CSRFToken to Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063612/adding-csrftoken-to-ajax-request)

c) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: Check by removing contentType.

Comment: Are you directly getting the `csrf_token` from the template?

Comment: I tried removing contentType to no avail. tried getting the token in any number of ways

Comment: I was thinking: is it possible that I may be missing something major along the way? Would something like this be solved were I to upgrade django (this would be something possibile as the project is small in size and not that client sensitive)

Answer (score 3):

```
let csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}'
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers:{'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken},
    url: "{% url 'Wishlist' %}",
    data: {'product_id':product_id},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response, typeof(response))
    }
})
```

I used simple ajax with csrf in the header and it's working fine.

when i use your code in mine, so function calls but data gets blank. i have refered this [Django csrf token for Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700954/django-csrf-token-for-ajax/51701012)